How to reduce boilerplate code by generics
There are few structs which conform to common protocol:
protocol StateMachineState {...}

struct VideoMode: StateMachineState {    
    func transit(state: PhotoMode) -> Transition? {
        return Transition(targetState: state)
    }
}

struct PhotoMode: StateMachineState {    
    func transit(state: VideoMode) -> Transition? {
        return Transition(targetState: state)
    }
}

and the usage of the member method of such:
func transit(target_state: PhotoMode) {
    process(transition: state.transit(state: target_state))
}

func transit(target_state: VideoMode) {
    process(transition: state.transit(state: target_state))
}

Notice, there is the same implementation in all func transit(), they differ only in parameter type. Both VideoMode and PhotoMode conform to the same protocol. The goal is to reduce code repetition and try to apply Generics? to write one common function accepting all the types conform to common protocol. I assume the state.transit(...) call requires the concrete type - either VideoMode or PhotoMode to be identified somehow... something like:
func transit<Mode: StateMachineState>(target_state: Mode) {     // Mode equals StateMachineState
    try process(transition: state.transit(state: target_state)) // Requires VideMode or PhotoMode
}

The code reports "Not exact matches in call to instance method transit" and offers the candidates using VideoMode and PhotoMode respectively.
Is there a way to use the generics to let the compiler generate the repetitive methods on its own or I have to write and repeat all over by myself (The body is always the same)?
(I am coming from C++ world where it is pretty common technique but in Swift I struggle to make it compiled and run...)

What members does the StateMachineState protocol declare?

I'm assuming each state would only have one transit method that takes a parameter of another state type? i.e. No state will have both func transit(state: StateA) and func transit(state: StateB). Is that right?

Each state can have multiple transit member methods. It is part of state machine implementation and the transitions between the states can have multiple ways…

So what’s inside the protocol? You still haven’t answered that yet. It appears that you need a double dispatch mechanism here. Swift doesn’t have that. What you have done here looks like a visitor pattern, which is exactly the pattern to simulate double dispatch.

As you haven’t provided full code, I have to make some assumptions, but…

There is no need to keep confirming to the protocol one by one. You can write extensions for protocols:

extension StateMachineState {
    func transit<Other: StateMachineState>(state: Other) -> Transition? { 
        return Transition(targetState: state)
    }
}

(assuming your Transition type supports this)

Now, assuming state is not a concrete implementation of StateMachineState, you can do this:

class SomeType<SMS: StateMachineState> {
    var state: SMS

    func transit<Other: StateMachineState>(target_state: Other) { 
        try process(transition: state.transit(state: target_state))
    }
}

This way, you never use concrete types during implementation and can access the extension method on the Protocol from the process() argument.
